# UV unwrap triangles/flatten curved surface

Tags: mesh, uv, vertices

Some time ago I made a piece of a prism turned towards the sky and now I want to make it in metal, so it had occurred to me to make a UV unwrap on the sides so that I had them flat, then vectorized them and sent them to a laser cutting machine for later mount them.

Prior to this, I was trying to do it with sheets of paper and I'm seeing that the sides don't fit. Reading through the forums I have seen that for an unwrap to be a faithful flattening I have to do the step of "follow active quads" but this object that I made is made of triangles and when I perform the action of "tris to quads" it does not transform all of the triangles.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: For what you're describing, you don't want a follow active quads unwrap; you want the unwrap you're showing.  Except you have to be aware that each piece won't work as a flat piece of metal.  They need to be scored at all edges so that they can bend along those lines and along no other lines.

Comment: Hi Nathan,

First of all thank you for your reply.

In the unwrap that I attached it shows that, right?

The sides are perfectly separated by the edges that join them. However when joining these planes back on metal, paper or any material they do not conform to each other :(

Comment: No, there are more edges than that.  Every face is a triangle, with three edges.